# Mapping Elements in a Form (for Formik)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mapping, material-ui

In my form, I am using Formik/Yup for Validation. Currently, this works in my form perfectly:

```
export default function AddUserPage() {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ firstName: "", email: "" }}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            actions.setSubmitting(false);
          }, 1000);
        }}
        validationSchema={schema}
      >
        {props => {
          const {
            values: { firstName, lastName, email, password, phone },
            errors,
            touched,
            handleChange,
            isValid,
            setFieldTouched
          } = props;
          const change = (name: string, e: any) => {
            e.persist();
            handleChange(e);
            setFieldTouched(name, true, false);
          };
          return (
            <div className="main-content">
              <form style={{ width: "100%" }}>
                <div>
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="firstName"
                    name="firstName"
                    helperText={touched.firstName ? errors.firstName : ""}
                    error={touched.firstName && Boolean(errors.firstName)}
                    label="First Name"
                    //onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
                    value={firstName}
                    onChange={change.bind(null, "firstName")}
                  />
                  <br></br>
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ""}
                    error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                    label="Email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={change.bind(null, "email")}
                  />
                  <br></br>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, instead of typing everything, I want to map my text fields. How could I map my text fields?

I tried something like this but I get errors for helperText and error properties:

```
{[{ label: "First Name", state: firstName , type: "text", function: setFirstName},
{ label: "Email", state: email , type: "text", function: setEmail},
  ]}.map((item, index) => (
  <div>
    <TextField
      id="outlined-basic"
      key={index}
      label={item.label}
      variant="outlined"
      type= {item.type}
      helperText= {touched[item.state] ? errors[item.state] : ""}
      onChange={change.bind(null, state)}        
    />
    <br></br><br></br>
  </div>
)
```

Here, I get an error on helper text that:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'FormikTouched<{ firstName: string; lastName: string; email: string; password: string; phone: string; }>'

I tried adding this as well but this also gives me an error:

`helperText = {touched.item.state}`

Comment: `touched.{item.state}` this is not valid JS.

Comment: What alternative could I use? A bit new to this. @evolutionxbox

Comment: Maybe using bracket notation? `touched[item.state]`

Comment: Nope, didn't work

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Was there an error?

Comment: Could you please see my updated qs?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your second code sample. `]}.map` probably should be `].map(` and the ending `)` should be `))}`.

Comment: Oh that's probably because I removed a few items from the map before posting here. But it doesn't work anyway @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an synthetic error figure bracket before .map

this code render some jsx with map:

```
[
  { label: "First Name",  type: "text"},
{ label: "Email",  type: "text"},
  ].map((item, i) => (
  <div>
    <TextField
      key={i}
      label={item.label}
      type= {item.type}    
    />
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Oh that's probably because I removed a few items from the map before posting here. But that's not what my problem/question is

Comment: I want to know how I can map items like these: ```helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ""}
                    error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
```